# Adding enabling and disabling as context menu on a grid in extjs

Tags: extjs

Hi I have added one context menu on my grid which will perform the enable and disable functionality for selected row. I am new to ExtJs. I have added below listener for the grid. How to add enable and disable functionality for the grid row?

```
listeners: {
    itemcontextmenu: function (grid, record, item, index, e) {
        var contextMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
            controller: 'grid-controller',
            width: 165,
            plain: true,
            items: [{
                text: 'Disable',
                listeners: {
                    click: {fn: 'disable', extra: record}
                },
            }]
        });
        e.stopEvent();
        contextMenu.showAt(e.getXY());
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check

Comment: What do you mean by disable? Not selectable? Greyed out? Besides, it is not a good practice to create the context menu in the listener. Research on how to create the menu only once for the grid.

Comment: Disabling means non selectable. Do you anything I can refer for my reference? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not a copy-paste answer, but going through the following steps with doing your own research you can solve your problem.

**1. Create the context menu only once and destroy it**

In you code, the context menu is created every time when the user opens up the menu on the grid. This is not good. Instead, create the context menu only once when the grid is created, and destroy it when the grid is destroyed. Something like this:

```
Ext.define('MyGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    initComponent : function() {
        this.callParent();
        this.MyMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
            items: [...]
        });
        this.on({
            scope : this,
            itemcontextmenu : this.onItemContextMenu
        });
    },
    onDestroy : function() {
        if (this.MyMenu) {
            this.MyMenu.destroy();
        }
    },
    onItemContextMenu : function(view, rec, item,index, event) {
        event.stopEvent();
        this.MyMenu.showAt(event.getXY());
    }
});
```

**2. Store enabled / disabled state in the record**

For the next step to work, records in your grid must contain whether the corresponding row is enabled or disabled. In the context menu, when user selects enabled / disabled, store this status like this, get `record` of the row where the context menu was displayed from:

```
record.set('myDisabledState', true); // or false
```

It is important to store the disabled state (and not enabled), because when your grid initially is rendered, these values won't be in the records, so `record.get('myDisabledState')` will evaluate to `FALSE`, and that is the desired behaviour, if you want to start with every row being able to be selected.

**3. Disable selection**
Now you can add a `beforeselect` listener to your grid, [see documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#event-beforeselect). This listeners receives `record` as parameter, and *if you return `false` from this listener, the selection will be canceled*. So in this listener simply add:

```
listeners: {
    beforeselect: function ( grid, record, index, eOpts ) {
        return !record.get('myDisabledState');
    }
}
```

**4. Apply formatting - OPTIONAL**

It is likely that you want to add different formatting for disabled rows, for example grey colour. The easiest way to do it is to add a custom CSS style to your `Application.scss` file:

```
.my-disabled-row .x-grid-cell-inner {
    color: gray;
}
```

Finally add `getRowClass` configuration to your grid, it will receive the current record being rendered, and you can return the above custom CSS style when the row is disabled:

```
Ext.define('MyGrid', {
    // your grid definition
    ,
    viewConfig: {
        getRowClass: function (record, rowIndex, rowParams, store) {
            if (record.get('myDisabledState')) {
                return "my-disabled-row";
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In this last part, when row is not disabled, it will return nothing, so default formatting will be used.