# If else condition inside listener for context menu in extjs

Tags: extjs

I have following function for my context menu for the grid. I have two functions in the controller where I am making the api call for the context menu (for enabling and disabling). These functions are "disableRule" for Disable context menu and "enableRule" for Enable context menu. I am checking the state of the row of the grid to showcase the menu in the context menu, and this this state I am storing in  the enabled variable. Now I want to call the function for the Disable and Enable context menu. How can I call the both the function according to the condition. For the gridText I want to call functions according to the condition.

```
itemcontextmenu: function (grid, record, item, index, e) {

            var enabled = grid.getStore().getAt(index).get( 'enabled' ) == 1 ? true : false;
            if(enabled){
                gridText = 'Disable'
            } else {
                gridText = 'Enable'
            }
            var contextMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
                controller: 'administration-ipaccessmanagement',
                width: 100,
                plain: true,
                items: [{
                    text: 'Delete',
                    listeners: {
                        click: {fn: 'deleteRule', extra: record}
                    }
                },{
                    text: gridText,
                    listeners: {
                            click: {fn: 'disableRule', extra: record}
                    }
                }

                ]
            });
            e.stopEvent();
            contextMenu.showAt(e.getXY());
        }
```

Comment: As I wrote in an earlier answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68767928/adding-enabling-and-disabling-as-context-menu-on-a-grid-in-extjs), this way you will create many context menus, one each time when the menu is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an item based on `enabled`. You just create a menu-item (button) on the fly.

```
itemcontextmenu: function (grid, record, item, index, e) {

    const enabled = !!grid.getStore().getAt(index).get( 'enabled' );

    const enableDisableItem = {
        text: enabled ? 'Enable' : 'Disable',
        listeners: {
            click: {
                fn: enabled ? 'enableRule' : 'disableRule',
                extra: record
            }
        }
    };


    var contextMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
            controller: 'administration-ipaccessmanagement',
            width: 100,
            plain: true,
            items: [{
                text: 'Delete',
                listeners: {
                    click: {fn: 'deleteRule', extra: record}
                }
            },
                enableDisableItem
            ]
        });

    e.stopEvent();
    contextMenu.showAt(e.getXY());
}
```